# upload base64 pdf file to s3 using nodejs unable to open at s3 but able to download and then open it works fine

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload base64 file at s3 but unable to open from s3 but if i click on download and then open the same file then it works fine able to open without any issue

Here is my code:

```
  const fileStream = Buffer.from(Attachments[i].bytes, 'base64'),
  const s3 = new AWS.S3();
  const contentType = mime.contentType(path.extname(fileName));
  const params = {
  Bucket: bucket,
  Key: s3Key,
  ContentEncoding: 'base64',
  Body: fileStream,
} as PutObjectRequest;
if (contentType !== false) {
  params.ContentType = contentType;
}
const putPromise = s3.upload(params).promise();
const [err, response] = await to(putPromise);
```

Did i miss something

Comment: Can you give us some more context ? Where is the code running and which error do you get ?

Answer (score 0):

copy file link and paste in your browser this will open your file in browser